# Custom Field value not visible on a view

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spfield

I have created a custom field based on SPFieldUrl. What I want, is basically just a normal Url field functionality, but I don't want it to be visible when new item is added to the list (a webpart is filling it). The problem is, i cant see the value on the default view of this list, but when I edit the items, I can see that the value is set correctly

heres my xml definition:

```
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">NonEditableLinkField</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">URL</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">Non Editable Link Field</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">programaticaly set url</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="Sortable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="Filterable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowInNewForm">FALSE</Field>
    <Field Name="AllowBaseTypeRendering">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">MyProject.NonEditableLinkField,$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Field>
  </FieldType>
```

NonEditableLinkField.cs has nothing but constructors at this moment. Perhaps anyone knows where the problem is?

Comment: Why create a custom field instead of setting ShowInNewForm to false on an instance of SPFieldUrl?

Comment: well i ended up doing it this way, I was looking [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2008/07/07/how-to-customize-rendering-of-sharepoint-list-form-fields-part-1.aspx), and somehow missed the 3rd option before

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually checked that the field is checked as Display in the view you are using?

Comment: yup, the field was visible on the view, there was just no values in rows